# Increase the bottom margin in QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

I need to make the scrollbar enabled even if the number of lines is less than the height of the QTextEdit, like in below pic

I tried `setDocumentMargin()` but it makes margin in all directions (left, right, top, and bottom)

So, is there a way to increase only the bottom margin of the QTextEdit.

[image: Edit Area with larger margin]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you observe the [source code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/e4c39d5e1e7ee8c2bba273e6d613ec519b7fa9c2/src/gui/text/qtextdocument.cpp#L740), we see that the function is defined as follows:

```
void QTextDocument::setDocumentMargin(qreal margin)
{
    // ...
    QTextFrame* root = rootFrame();
    QTextFrameFormat format = root->frameFormat();
    format.setMargin(margin);
    root->setFrameFormat(format);
    // ...
}
```

So we can do the same through the functions `rootFrame()` and `frameFormat()` as I show below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    textEdit = QTextEdit()

    format = textEdit.document().rootFrame().frameFormat()
    format.setBottomMargin(10)
    # format.setTopMargin(value)
    # format.setLeftMargin(value)
    # format.setRightMargin(value)
    textEdit.document().rootFrame().setFrameFormat(format)

    textEdit.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you just want to make a QTextEdit scrollbar visible, use the following:

```
textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
```

Comment: I tried that, but not working with me. Still the scrollbar hidden

Comment: @MoatazEl-Ibiary What is your goal? The margins or the scrollbar?

Comment: My goal is to make the scrollbar enabled. I was trying to do that using margins. But the margin is not my target

Comment: I recommend you put as a title something more direct because it should show your main objective, in your explanation you can describe what you tried.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out why it wasn't working. The problem was that 10 in `format.setBottomMargin(10)` is so small, so the bottom margin wasn't enough to show the scrollbar. 

`textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)` was unnecessary after adjusting the bottom margin.